# Error in Synchronize Translation Openerp 7

Tags: python, odoo

I am getting this strange error when trying to synchronize terms in Openerp 7.

I had imported some terms for german language through a CSV file before but now I only have English installed.

```
OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
result=self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db,self.session._uid,self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
res = fn(db, uid, *params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/base/module/wizard/base_update_translations.py", line 47, in act_update
tools.trans_export(this.lang, ['all'], buf, 'csv', cr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/opener/tools/translate.py", line 496, in trans_export
translations = trans_generate(lang, modules, cr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/opener/tools/translate.py", line 788, in trans_generate
push_translation(module, 'model', name, xml_name, encode(trad))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20131124_002547-py2.6.egg/opener/tools/translate.py", line 648, in push_translation
if not source or len(source.strip()) <= 1:
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution to my problem:
I had set a few custom boolean fields to "translatable" in my models. Un-checking the "translatable" property on them removed the errors.